# What is the need for dipole moment if electronegativity already exists?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, polarity, dipole

Say we have an HCl molecule. The difference in electronegativities of the H and Cl atoms tells us how polar the HCl molecule is. The dipole moment is also a measure of the degree of polarity in molecules.

So why do we need the "dipole moment" concept if we can see how polar a molecule is by looking at the electronegativities of the atoms in the molecule? Is it because in complex molecules it is easier to measure how polar a molecule is, using the dipole moment formula?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have any questions regarding how the site works, please feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help]. Best of luck with your question!

Comment: Well, electronegativity difference tells us like almost nothing.

Comment: Dipole moment **is** a measure. Electronegativity is but a vague hint.

Comment: As @Ivan Neretin writes, the dipole moment is the experimental measurement so comes first , so you have your ideas the wrong way round.

Comment: Electronegativities can only qualitatively predict the nature of a bond in a molecule. For quantitative requirements,the concept of dipole moment is required.